# Algorithm behind scipy.ndimage.measurements.label

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, labeling

I sadly cannot find anything on how the "scipy.ndimage.measurements.label" algorithm works but need to know that for my thesis that I have to hand in way too soon. Is there anyone who can help me out here? Here the scipy link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html and also from the github page where the source links to, I cannot find anything about it.

I could also not find anythin in the more extensive scipy docs (chapter 1.14.7  Segmentation and labeling):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/scipy-ref-0.16.0.pdf

Any ideas what algorithm is implemented here? It would mean a lot to me if anyone could help! Cheers!

Comment: This is connected component analysis. There are a million and one algorithms for it out there. [YACCLAB](http://imagelab.ing.unimore.it/yacclab) collects and compares the most prominent algorithms. That is probably a good resource to read about the concepts.

Comment: Looking at the `github` link, it looks most of work is done in `_ni_label`, which I believe is this `cythoin` code:  `scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx`.  Sometimes files like this implement the calculation itself, other times they interface to external code.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! You are right about the _ni_label.pyx
I cannot read cython, is anyone able to tell me which approach is used here? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/ndimage/src/_ni_label.pyx
The commenting is not very instructive after the beginning (forground extraction). That would be wonderful!